# Angular Router.navigate function just reloads same page

Tags: angular

In browser url field the url that I want to go just appears for less then 1 second and page reloads the current page. In my component I have created function to navigate to another page but through this function it does not work. But when I write the url directly in browser url field then its works.

**I have represented this issue in this stackblitz app. Please check it for better undestanding.**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lzfvru

Here is my files:

```
// app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

---

the function `onRegister()` call was supposed to transfer me to another page.

```
// login.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onLogin() {
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedin', 'true');
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  }

  onRegister() {
    this.router.navigate(['/register']);
  }
}
```

---

```
// login-routes.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LoginRoutingModule {}
```

**And there is the module that I want to load**

```
// register.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  createAccount() {}
}
```

---

```
// register-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RegisterComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RegisterRoutingModule {}
```

So looks my project three

[image]

And my router guard

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedin') || this.router.url === '/register') {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Through button click which calls method `router.navigate(['/register'])`
[image]

Writing url directly in browser url field
[image]

Comment: not sure why you need to create modules for login and register in `app-routing.module.ts`. Could you try using `component: LoginComponent` and `component: RegisterComponent` in `app-routing.module.ts`?

Comment: instead of `loadChildren?`

Comment: yeah, sorry, i should have clarified. component instead of load children.

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Component LoginComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.`

I got following error, despite the fact that I have added both Components in theyr modules. Ill not add them to `app.modules.ts`.

Comment: you need to add `LoginComponent` and `RegisterComponent` to `app.modules.ts` under `declarations`

Answer (score -1):

Problem is arising, when your application is not able to find `RegisterComponent`.

In order to fix that, you need to add `loginModule` into your `app.module.ts`.

Add following in the `app.module.ts`.

```js
...

import { LoginModule } from './login/login.module';

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    ... ,
    LoginModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Happy to help!

Comment: I want to load `loginModule` only in case that some one goes to `/login` url

Comment: Remove `canActivate: [AuthGuard]` from `app-routing.module.ts`. It will bypass the authGuard, which was causing the error. Refer [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdcasq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts)